# Change edit function in windows form

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms

I'm using visual studio 2019 and i'm making some program with database.
There is **2** **table** on **database**.

1. branch
2. user

In branch table there is a total user.

At the program, in user form, there is a **save** **button** and this button have two function, like save and edit.

Now i want to make save button :

In edit function, if one user is want to change the branch of the company, total user in old company is decrease or (-1 user) and total user in new company is increase or (+1 user)

This the code where i'm stuck with it

```
Else
 Dim edit As String
            edit = "Update user set branch_id='" & Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 1) &
                    "', name='" & TextBox1.Text &
                    "', username='" & TextBox2.Text &
                    "', password='" & TextBox3.Text &
                    "', level='" & ComboBox2.Text &
                    "' where id='" & var_id & "'"

            cmd = New OdbcCommand("select * from branch where id='" + Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 1) + "'", conn)
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            rd.Read()
            If rd.HasRows Then
                Dim edit2 As String
                edit2 = "Update branch set total='" & rd.Item("total") + 1 &
                    "' where id='" & Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 1) & "'"
                cmd = New OdbcCommand(edit2, conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If

            cmd = New OdbcCommand(edit, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Passwords should never be stored.  Not very clear what question you are asking.

Comment: I'm just edit my post, its really hard to explain my problem in English language @LarsTech

Comment: You don't need to store the "total" in the branch table.  Just query the user table for how many users have that branch_id.

Comment: But, my code is still false, because in edit function i want to make total in branch database is decrease and increase following this user form @LarsTech

Comment: Delete the total field.  You don't need it.  You are also not executing your "edit" sql.  And like I said, learn to use parameters.